# Select field in grails workflow

Tags: forms, grails, spring-webflow

I have a problem prefilling a dropdown list in an grails webflow

I have a controller for the webflow

```
 class ClearanceRequestController {

def index() {
    redirect(action: "start")
}

def startFlow = {
    contact {
        on('next') {
            flow.developer = params.developer
            flow.project = params.project
            flow.projectResponsible = params.projectResponsible
            flow.email = params.email

            [flow : flow]
        }.to('application')
        on('cancel').to('finish')
   ...
```

and the view looks like this:
contact.gsp

```
  <g:if test="${message}">
        <div class="message">${message}</div>
    </g:if>
    <g:form action="start" method="post">
        <div class="dialog">
            <table>
            <tbody>
             <tr class="prop">
                    <td valign="top" class="name">
                        <label for="projectName">Projekt:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input type="text" id="projectName" name="project" value="${params.project}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <g:select name="state" from="${Project?.DIVISION_OPTIONS}" value="${Project?.DIVISION_OPTIONS}"/>
```

This is the Project definition

```
  class Project {

static DIVISION_OPTIONS = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

String name
String division


String toString(){
    "$name"
}


static constraints = {
    name(unique: true)
    division(inList: DIVISION_OPTIONS)

 }
}
```

I don't know how to get the data from the constraints. I tried to access

```
 Project.constraints.division.inList
```

or

```
 Project.DIVISION_OPTIONS
```

but both didn't worked. I assume I have to initialize the Project somewhere and pass it to the contact.gsp, but I don't know how.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the "?" from Project?.DIVISON_OPTIONS I get "Cannot get property 'DIVISION_OPTIONS' on null object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it, just import the `Project` in the page, like

```
<%@ page import="com.companyName.Project" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

or like:

```
 <g:select name="state" from="${com.companyName.Project?.DIVISION_OPTIONS}" value="${com.companyName.Project?.DIVISION_OPTIONS}"/>
```